# Replace Docx header/footer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have looked around and can't seem to find any recent answers. We need to update the header & footer on our documents in SharePoint. What I want to do is create a template header & footer, that will replace the current header & footer of a document when it is approved.

Workflow should be something like this:

1. Upload/edit document.
2. Submit for approval.
3. Document approved.
4. Header template is loaded and updated with latest version no/approved by/modified by.
5. Footer template is loaded and updated with latest version no.
6. Document published to site and available to users.

The reason I want to replace the header and footer is to ensure that each document uses the same format header & footer, and it will allow for contributors to upload a document without the need for them to use a template, and if they load one with another header/footer it will be replaced by the correct ones.

This is to ensure all our documents are standardized and to comply with ISO requirements.

**NOTE**: I am not a full time SharePoint dev (we don't have one), so my background in this is very limited. Thank you for your understanding. If there are better options I am open for them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop SharePoint Server custom workflow actions. Which are extensions that allow you to create customized functionalities within SharePoint workflows. I personally using the same action to manipulate doc and docx files.

To develop custom workflow actions for SharePoint Server, you generally need some components and environments;

- SharePoint Designer: This is a tool provided by Microsoft for
  creating and customizing workflows in SharePoint. While it's not the
  only tool available, it's often used for building simple workflows
  and custom actions. It allows you to create reusable workflows and
  incorporate custom actions using a visual interface.
- Visual Studio: For more complex and advanced custom workflow actions,
  you can use Microsoft Visual Studio. It provides a more robust
  development environment for building custom actions using programming
  languages like C#.
- Deployment: Once you've developed your custom workflow actions,
  you'll need to deploy them to your SharePoint environment. The
  deployment process might involve uploading the assembly to the Global
  Assembly Cache (GAC) on the SharePoint server and registering the
  custom actions with SharePoint so they can be used in your workflows.
- SharePoint Environment: Of course, you need a SharePoint Server
  environment to deploy and use your custom workflow actions. These
  actions are typically deployed to a specific site collection, and the
  workflows that use them are created and executed within that
  environment.

I don't think there is any other way to manipulate documents without writing a code. Here is a short example of [custom action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-build-and-deploy-workflow-custom-actions).